# find a specific range of cells with a certain cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a script for an excel document that will give back a cell range which has a specific cell value in a column, so that I can then count on another column in that range on how many are green, amber or red.  Here is an example of the excel document: -

```
Type    Reference   Department  Colour
Large   20                      Green
Large   21                      Green
Large   2                       Amber
Large   23                      Amber
Large   5                       Green
Medium  6                       Red
Medium  23                      Green
Medium  8                       Green
Medium  10                      Red
Small   11                      Amber
Small   12                      Red
Small   16                      Green
Small   17                      Green
Small   33                      Green
Small   36                      Amber
Small   55                      Amber
```

This is the script I have but it is only finding the second cell number with that value.  I need to find the range of all of 'Large', 'Medium' and 'Small'.

```
Set rngFindValue = ActiveSheet.Range("H22:H" & lastRow).Find(What:="Medium", After:=ActiveSheet.Range("H22"), LookIn:=xlFormulas)
            If Not rngFindValue Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox rngFindValue.Address
            End If
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.  This is the new code I have, I am able to get the first cell in the range and the last cell: -

```
Dim mediumStartRow As Integer
Dim mediumEndRow As Integer

        mediumStartRow = Range("H:H").Find(what:="Medium Project", after:=Range("H21")).Row
        mediumEndRow = Range("H:H").Find(what:="Medium Project", after:=Range("H21"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        MsgBox "First and Last Row for Medium Projects: " & mediumStartRow & mediumEndRow
```

It seems to be working